# Start a For loop part way through a dictionary

Tags: vb.net

The code below is trying to work through a dictionary passed to this sub (this is not the whole sub - just what i thought was needed for this question) using the dictionary key and value to copy files. It works fine. I'm trying to allow the user to click a Pause button and then click a Resume button. As seen in this code I'm saving the counter value when the Pause is clicked in the holdctr1 variable. What I need to do is start the process again from the holdctr1 variable when the user clicks Resume. With a normal For statement that includes a From clause, this is easy, but I can't see how to do it here. I'm thinking that rather than using an integer counter I should be using the dictionary key value but whenever I try to put a From clause in the For statement I get an error. I'd appreciate any help, but please keep it simple as I'm just learning VB.

```
    For Each kvp In DirectCast(e.Argument, Dictionary(Of String, String))
        counter1 += 1

        ' Has the background worker been told to stop?
        If Me.BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending Then
            ' Set cancel to True
            e.Cancel = True
            ' ***********************************
            ' hold the counter value when  ******
            ' pause was pressed            ******
            holdctr1 = counter1 - 1       '******
            ' ***********************************
            Exit For
        End If

        strSourceFilePath = kvp.Key
        strDestFilePath = kvp.Value

        ' Do the file copy here
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(strSourceFilePath, strDestFilePath, overwrite:=False)

    Next
```

Comment: As an alternative, you could implement the enumeration yourself instead of using `For Each` to do it for you.  Then, if you keep the enumerator as a class-level variable, it's trivial to resume stepping it.  There's a little more ceremony that hides behind the `For Each` keywords but not much (perhaps less than you think).  The negative is that this can only work if the dictionary is unchanged (changing it will invalidate any existing enumerations).  On the other hand, the skip suggested below might have surprising behavior in that case as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `For Each` loop enumerates a list and you can call `Skip` on that list to ignore a specific number of leading items. In your case, that would mean using this:

```vb
For Each kvp In DirectCast(e.Argument, Dictionary(Of String, String)).Skip(counter1)
```

Of course, you should use a better name than `counter1` for that variable.

Comment: lol - I'm embarrassed to have to ask this but what's wrong with the variable name?  too descriptive? not descriptive enough? too easy to hack? I would like to know to avoid the problem in the future.

Comment: @RossfromBrooklin, based on your code, I think that I would likely use something like `filePathsProcessedCount`. I think that you can probably interpret my initial criticism from that. The fact that you have `counter1` implies that you might have `counter2` and there's an obvious problem there.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to restarting the enumeration and skipping ahead, you could write the enumeration explicitly, writing out the steps that `For Each` does behind the scenes for you.  Then you can keep the enumerator at the class level, making it trivial to resume.

e.g. a class variable of

```
Private _pathsEnumerator As Dictionary(Of String, String).Enumerator
```

(Unfortunately, because it's class-level, the type can't be inferred.)

And then your iteration would be something like

```
_pathsEnumerator = DirectCast(e.Argument, Dictionary(Of String, String).GetEnumerator()

Do While _pathsEnumerator.MoveNext()
    Dim kvp = _pathsEnumerator.Current

    'Remainder would be the same 
Loop

'Reset the enumerator if canceled.
If e.Cancel Then _pathsEnumerator = Nothing
```

Written this way, you could then resume by checking to see if the enumerator is null, and continuing if not.  Beware that if there is any chance of the dictionary changing, this would throw an exception, but you probably want that anyway; I'd worry about the logic in the other answer if this were to happen, you might find that by resuming you unintentionally skipped something.

You might want to defer your cancellation check until after you operate on the current item; otherwise, you would need some logic to manage repeating that item when you resume.  That would probably require tracking a "current item" in addition to the enumerator.  Implementation is left as an exercise for the reader.